# How to create CPU Flame Graphs for Delphi applications?

Tags: performance, delphi, stack-trace, flamegraph

I would like to visualize CPU usage of my Delphi application as a [Flame Graph](https://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) image. To make it work a periodical dump of the function names existing on the call stack is required. How can I make a dump of the application call stack in Delphi and map it to the function names?

I have tried to use the `madStackTrace` unit from [madExcept](http://help.madshi.net/madExcept.htm) but calling its `stackTrace()` function takes around 170ms on my computer which makes it a bad choice for taking probes multiple times per second. Maybe there is a way to dump the raw callstack adresses, and resolve them into function names in a later step?

Comment: Use a profiler, for example the ones provided by Intel or AMD which have flame graphs

Comment: I'm afraid a generic Windows profiler would not show Delphi function names on the callstack due to missing support for parsing the Delphi-specific "project.map" files. Or will they?

Comment: They do if you use map2pdb, that's what I do. Writing a profiler is a huge task. Don't try. Use one that exists and does the job already.

Comment: And just to complete Davids comment: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4853-map2pdb-profiling-with-vtune/